# Font Awesome Icon not working in .NET/MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, font-awesome, nuget-package

Kind of simple as the title says but I'm struggling with the steps. I downloaded font-awesome from Nuget Package Manager and added it to my project.

[image]

I also added the the font-awesome css in my bundle config file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css"));
```

Content/CSS is loaded on my main layout page, which all subsequent pages inherit from.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

But trying to use the icons in a button form:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Story", new { id = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
                    Edit Story
</a>
```

[image]

Results in nothing showing up. What am I missing in the steps?

Comment: fas fa-adjust Please change it to "fa fa-adjust"

Comment: The class in your code is it fas or fa?

Comment: on font awesome website it says <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i> but I changed it to fa fa-adjust and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @AsifRaza that worked for me too. Changed fas to fa. Thank you. Maybe you should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check:

1. Did you also include the actual fonts and did you place them on the
   folder that is referenced inside your font-awesome.css file(search for
   @font-face tag ,url property)
2. Are you also loading javascript(fontawesome.js) and including it inside ScriptBundle?

There are dozens of NuGet Packages for font-awesome today however I prefer to be in control so this is the way to manually install Font Awesome in ASP.NET MVC:

1. Download font awesome zip package from official website.
2. Create a folder inside Content subfolder and name it something like "font-awesome".
3. Copy css and webfonts folders from downloaded zip package to the folder created in step 2.
4. Copy js folder content to your Scripts folder
5. In your bundle config, include "~/Content/font-awesome/css/all.css" and also
   "~Scripts/fontawesome.js".
6. Done